# Normalized cumulative discounted gain formula in R

Tags: r, function, recommendation-engine

I would like to code in R the next formula in a function:

[image: normalized cumulative discount gain]

Which it is supposed to be in an R package but once installed the package is not there...

```
# original source: 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rrecsys/versions/0.9.5.4/topics/nDCG
#Alternative source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain
```

The use of the function is with two vectors as inputs.

```
# example
v1=c(1,2,3,4)
v2=c(1,3,2,4)
nDGC(v1,v2)
```

anyone could help me to code it in an efficient way?

## A python version of DGC is:

```
rel = zip(range(1,7),[3,2,3,0,1,2])
dcg6 = rel[0][1] + sum(map(lambda (a,b):b/math.log(a,2),rel[1:]))
print dcg6
```

Comment: what is `rel` in your example?

Comment: I take it `rel` is `v1` and `v2`, but what is `|h|`?

Comment: could we change into wikipedia's formulation if its celarer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward R implementation of the equations in Wikipedia with some error-checking included:

---

### First equation

[image]

```r
DCG_pos <- function(rel, p)
{
  if(missing(p)) p <- length(rel)
  stopifnot(p <= length(rel))

  sum(rel[seq(p)]/log(seq(p) + 1, 2))
}
```

---

### Second equation

[image]

```
IDCG_pos <- function(rel, p)
{
  if(missing(p)) p <- length(rel)
  stopifnot(p <= length(rel))

  sum((2^(rel[seq(p)]) - 1)/log(seq(p) + 1, 2))
}
```

---

### Third equation

[image]

```
nDGC_pos <- function(rel, p)
{
  if(missing(p)) p <- length(rel)
  stopifnot(p <= length(rel))

  DCG_pos(rel, p) / IDCG_pos(rel, p)
}
```

---

You can use them like this:

```
DCG_pos(1:5, 5)
#> [1] 7.41883
IDCG_pos(1:5, 5)
#> [1] 24.84537
nDGC_pos(1:5, 5)
#> [1] 0.2986
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: this looks nice! any advice of providing p argument or not?

Comment: The `p` argument is optional. If you have a vector of 10 numbers, you can specify whether you just want the first `p` numbers included. If you leave it blank, `p` will default to the length of `rel`

Comment: Awesome, outstanding!